# How do I show all whitespace log4j supplied messages?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I supply a formatted java string with significant whitespace

```
String.format("%1$12s %2$15s", "someString", "anotherOne");
```

to be logged using the following conversion pattern in log4j

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1} %m%n" />
```

In the logs, I receive the variable with just a single preceding whitespace.

```
... PatternStuff ... someString anotherOne
```

slf4j version 1.7.3
log4j version 1.2.14

Is it possible to show the whitespace added by String.format? Some other conversion pattern variable other than %m?

Comment: `I receive the variable with just a single preceding whitespace.` I cannot reproduce. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Have you tried using `EnhancedPatternLayout` in the extras package?

Answer (score 0):

My workplace has an internal web-based logviewer that quickly gives developers a way to access the contents of log files. We have the ability to print logs out in a generated webpage or to download the log. When I view them in the browser, the spaces are collapsed (because of standard HTML output). However, when I download the log files, they appear with the given formatting! Sorry for the confusion.